# Odoo - Invoke python function from the qweb report

Tags: python, xml, odoo-10, qweb

```
<tbody>
  <tr t-foreach="o.line_ids.filtered(lambda line: line.appears_on_payslip)" t-as="line">
    <t t-if="line.code in ('BASIC','OT','DED','GROSS','NET')">
       <td><span t-field="line.code"/></td>
       <td><span t-field="line.name"/></td>
       <td><span t-field="line.quantity"/></td>
       <td><span t-field="line.amount" t-esc-options='{"widget": "monetary", "display_currency": o.company_id.currency_id}'/></td>
       <td><span t-field="line.total" t-esc-options='{"widget": "monetary", "display_currency": o.company_id.currency_id}'/></td>
    </t>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

The above code is body of a table in qweb report. Instead of "line.quantity", I want to invoke a python function "o.compute_overtime()" and write as:

```
<t t-if="line.code=='OT'">
 <td><span t-esc="i['ot_total']"/></td>
</t>
```

How can I invoke the function for just 1 field?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create one parser class and in that you need to define one function which you can access from it's report.

```
from openerp import models
from openerp.report import report_sxw

class report_invoice_parser(report_sxw.rml_parse):
    def __init__(self, cr, uid, name, context=None):
        super(report_invoice_parser, self).__init__(cr,uid,name,context=context)
        self.localcontext.update({ 
                'get_name':self._get_name,
                })
        self.context=context

    def _get_name(self,line):

        if line.invoice_id.write_description == True:
            return line.name

        if line.product_id:
            if line.product_id.default_code:
                return "[%s] %s"%(line.product_id.default_code,line.product_id.name)
            else:
                return line.product_id.name
        else:
            line.name

class report_invoice(models.TransientModel):
    _name = "report.account.report_invoice"
    _inherit ="report.abstract_report"
    _template="account.report_invoice"
    _wrapped_report_class =report_invoice_parser
```

And in xml you need to call it as follow.

```
<tr t-foreach="o.invoice_line" t-as="l">
    <td><span t-esc="get_name(l)"/></td>
</tr>
```

You need to set your business logic in function, I have just share idea here. By this way you can call your method instead of field you can display function result.